# Duvidas Fetch + React Native

Tags: javascript, react, fetch, native

beleza?? Estou desenvolvendo um App com o Expo para um cliente, porém quando consulto (via código de barras) a API dele, sempre a primeira vez retorna um Array vazio, caso eu faça a consulta em seguida os dados são retornados. Sabem me dizer o motivo? Esse app lê código de barras, então criei um componente de leitor e ele retorna o código e lê da API

Tentei verificar a sintaxe das funções, mudar para async, remover o async, etc e nada resolve. Continua igual

Segue o código

```
const [data, setData] = useState('');
const [produto, setProduto] = useState([]);

const onCodeScanned = (data) => {
    setData(data);
    
    fetch(`http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8090/rest/COLETPRC?codbarras=${data}`)
    .then((response)=>response.json())
    .then((json)=>{
        setProduto(json.produtos[0]);
        console.log(produto); 
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });
    setModalVisible(false);
};
```

Saberiam me dizer o motivo disso estar acontecendo?
Segue uma tela com o que ocorre

[image: Console.log]

Comment: Você tentou usar `async/await` onde? Na função `onCodeScanned`? Você sabe que `setProduto` é assincrono logo o `console.log(produto);` só vai mostrar o valor passado e não o atualizado pelo `setProduto`.

Comment: Bom dia. Resolvido "encurtando" o caminho.
Dessa forma eu removi o useState Produtos e passei direto o retorno para o console.log().

Troquei a linha
`setProduto(json.produtos[0]); console.log(produto);`

por somente
`console.log(json.produtos[0]);`